# Try to change a texture of an object under the mouse with mouseclick [Three.js]

Tags: three.js, textures, onmouseclick

actual i work on a system to change the texture of an object with a mouseclick.

My objects are build with this:

```
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 25, 200, 50 );
    wall = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, holzMaterial );
    wall.position.set(-150.5,0,0);
    wall.castShadow = true;
    wall.receiveShadow = true;
    wall.name = "Mauer";
    collidableMeshListwand.push(wall);
    scene.add(wall);
```

the textures are coded as:

```
var holzTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/holz.jpg' );
holzTexture.wrapS = holzTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
holzTexture.repeat.set( 1, 1 );
var holzMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: holzTexture } );

var himmelTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/himmel.jpg' );
himmelTexture.wrapS = himmelTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
himmelTexture.repeat.set( 1, 1 );
var himmelMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: himmelTexture } );
```

So finaly i wrote a function which recogcnize elements under the mouse and change it on clicking. For example changing shadows work with:

```
if (intersects[ 0 ].object.castShadow == true) {
intersects[ 0 ].object.castShadow = false;
}
else {
intersects[ 0 ].object.castShadow = true;
}
```

Now i want to change the texture, while using:

```
intersects[ 0 ].object.mesh.material.uniforms.texture.value(himmelMaterial);
intersects[ 0 ].object.mesh.material.uniforms.texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

But this dont work.

it would be great if somebody could help me. :)